# Convert elements in an excel cell into python list

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple values in a single cell in excel. I want to convert them into a list.

My excel cell is `Customer_ID,Signup_Date,Revenue`.

I used:

```py
meta3[meta3['Feed Name']=='NFL_2CR_CUSTOMER'].values.tolist()
```

This is giving `['Customer_ID,Signup_Date,Revenue']` but I want `['Customer_ID','Signup_Date','Revenue']`

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.split` before `values.tolist`:

```
>>> df['Col1'].str.split(',').values.tolist()
[['Customer_ID', 'Signup_Date', 'Revenue']]
```